# Migrate a RouteConfig file from ASP.Net MVC 4 to 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The following RouteConfig worked in ASP.NET MVC 4:

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapPageRoute(
                "Cuisine",
                "cuisine/{name}",
                new {controller = "Cuisine",action = "Search", name =""});

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

In ASP.Net MVC 5, the statement

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
                "Cuisine",
                "cuisine/{name}",
                new {controller = "Cuisine",action = "Search", name =""});
```

generates the error

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string controller, string action, string name>' to 'string'
```

Apparently, the signature of `MapRoute` has changed.

How can I migrate the code to ASP.Net MVC 5 ?

Comment: Having `name =""` does not really make sense. I assume you want `name = UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: The pattern should match anything in the form /Cuisine/French, Cuisine/Italian, etc.

Comment: `routes.MapPageRoute` is for WebForms. You should be using `routes.MapRoute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Cuisine",
            url: "cuisine/{name}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Cuisine",action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional});
```